# How do I access this variable from a different blueprint?

Tags: user-interface, variables, unreal-engine4

I have found loads of stuff like this on the Internet, but none of it is helping me and I would just love a direct response for *this* situation.

I have a text UI for my ammo which I simply want to access from the blueprint that handles firing. The text UI has a variable associated with it (At least, I assume this is my text UI):

[image: variable]

But for unknown reasons won't let me make it public. That doesn't seem to matter though, because I have experimented with other *public* variables and I can't access them from my blueprint either!

How can I get access to my variable here so I can do what I wish? 
[image: var]

Comment: Which version of UE are you using? And the second image is too low-resolution so I can't see details. By the way that variable `TextBock_49` should already be public, unless you check the `Private` checkbox of it in the `Details` panel. So if in any blueprint you can get the reference of this UMG, then you should be able to use this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found your other questions so I assume you're using 4.12, like myself.
So I can use the variable declared in UMG as follows:

Step 1, make a text block, enable it as `Is Variable`:

[image: Step 1]

Step 2, check it from the `Graph` part:

[image: Step 2]

Step 3, some other Blueprint, use it:

[image: Step 3]